# Manage Telerik backend push notifications based on data

Tags: push-notification, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder, everlive

I've been going around in circles today trying to figure out the best approach, but I'm still lost. Hoping someone here or the Telerik forums has the answer.

My user has a group of records with dates. I need to send a single push notification to the user for each unique date in that data.

I can create this push notification on the client side (appbuilder hybrid app) when a record is created. However, the client sdk for notifications only exposes create, not read or delete. That means -

1. I can't make sure there's only one notification per device, even if there are multiple records with the same date.
2. I can't change/remove the existing push notification if the date in a record is changed.

I thought about using Telerik Cloud Code for Data... But the sdk doesn't expose read/delete. I'd have to read all notifications for that User Id from the REST service and then determine which need to be updated/removed. That sounds like a mess of code for a scenario which I would consider somewhat normal. I'm also concerned about timing out, since there's a 5 second limit on cloud code for data.

So, what's the best way to manage my push notifications in Telerik backend services?

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in the Telerik Developer Forums here -> [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-based-push-creation-deletion)